# Find declare statement SQL Profiler

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a multiple EXEC statements being run, but the DECLARE is nowhere to be found. Below is what I'm seeing. I'm seeing thousands of these.

```
RPC:Completed | exec sp_execute 14,69 | TDS0X00000000030000001400730070005F0065007800650063007500740065001400000003000600380069006E0074000E0000001400000003000600380069006E
```

I do see declare statements for other Stored Procedures, just not for a few and they are the ones that I really need to analyze.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the source of these `sp_execute` calls? Are they coming in through SQL Native Client, or some other provider / layer?

Comment: Aaron, the source of the sp_execute calls is coming from our application. Here is a little more of a background on what I am doing. I am new to SQL (working toward a DBA) and I am trying to speed up some of our queries. So I start profiler and run the slow part of the application to see what queries are being run. I am getting thousands of sp_execute 14 statements all at 30ms.

Comment: There is no way for us to know what those calls are.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `RPC completed` (or maybe instead of), you should probably be capturing:

```
SP:Starting
SP:Completed
```

And if you want to see individual statements within those procedures, or the surrounding batches:

```
SP:StmtCompleted
SQL:StmtCompleted
SQL:BatchCompleted
```

That said, depending on how the statement is getting called and passed in, you may not always be able to catch every individual statement.